# Script firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've been struggling with finding a solution to this.

I have page which is for all devices, on desktop it loads jQuery and on mobile it switches to jQuery mobile.

I have a script on the page which loads info from a csv file and creates an li list, not it works well but for some reason on mobile devices it loads the li list twice. I've tried

```
$("#wrapper").live('pageinit', function() {
  // more stuff
});
```

And it worked on mobile but in desktop view it didn't load the li's. I also tried document.ready but the li's still loaded twice in mobile.

Here's the code:-

```
  <div>
  <form method="post" class="right">
      <div class="accnt_cont" >
      <div id="top5productlist" data-role="page" data-dom-cache="false">
      <div class="banner">
      <h2>View All Top 5</h2>
      </div>
      <ul id="tfive" class="listing">
       &nbsp;   
      </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /#producttabs --> <!-- include return_policy.cont.inc.html ENDS --></div>
      <!-- /.accnt_cont -->
  </form>
  </div>
  <script>
  (function() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
    xhr.open("GET", "example-data.csv");
    xhr.send();
    //display("Request sent");

    function handleStateChange() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 &&
          xhr.status >= 200 &&
          xhr.status < 300) {
        //display("Got response");
        showData(xhr.responseText);
      }
    }

    function showData(data) {
      var rows = data.split(/\n/);
      var rowNum;
      var cells;
      var cellNum;

      for (rowNum = 1; rowNum < rows.length; ++rowNum) {
        cells = rows[rowNum].split(",");  
          display('<li>' + cells[1] + '</li>');
      }
    }

    function display(msg) {
      var p = document.createElement('li');
      p.innerHTML = String(msg);
      document.getElementById("tfive").appendChild(p);
    }
  })();
  </script>
```

I want the script to work on desktop and mobile and only load the li's once. Any Suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you passing `'<li>' + cells[1] + '</li>'` and inserting it into the html, just pass `cells[1]` ?

Comment: There's allot of html which goes between the li's I cut most of it out as it's easier to read the code code that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try change your functions to

```
function showData(data) {
  var rows = data.split(/\n/);

  for (var rowNum = 1; rowNum < rows.length; ++rowNum) {
    var cells = rows[rowNum].split(",");  
      display(cells[1]);
  }
}

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('li');
  p.innerHTML = msg;
  document.getElementById("tfive").appendChild(p);
}
```

Comment: Hi, tried that and am still getting the li's loading twice on mobile. I think the issue is jquery mobile firing the script twice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it to work. After trying lots of different ways to call the function using JQuery all of them resulting in the script running twice, I decided to try plain javascript and it worked! I changed the function call to

```
window.onload = function(){
};
```

And now it only loads the script once.I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it but it works.